# Rerender layout

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Next.js 13 beta (app directory) and trying to dynamically change the navbar, which is in my root layout, based on the url path (navbar element will include the text "posts" at .../posts and "profile" at .../profile).

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { pathName: string };
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Navbar pathName={params.pathName} />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Based on [this](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/layout) page you can have a params argument but it doesn't include the page url. Also layouts don't get re-rendered so I am confused about how can I do this cleanly. Thank you.

Comment: Is Navbar a client component? No, you have params inside the layout only for routes with segments, like `[id]/Layout.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to pass params to Navbar element from layout, I directly used usePathname hook inside Navbar component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `useRouter` hook to get the correct `pathName`, as the `params` prop passed into the layout component will only include [dynamic route parameters](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#dynamic-segments), and [won't re-render](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/layout#good-to-know) on most page transitions for performance.

If you wanted to keep it all non-client-side, you could set up [group route layouts](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#route-groups) for each set of urls you want the navbar to be different at, but then you'd likely have some duplicated code.